# Calculate Years and Months since a Specific Date

Tags: javascript

I am just starting with Java Script. I am trying to come up with a simple solution to:

current date - indicated date with format "January  4, 2018" = years and months since the indicated date.

I looked at the [Datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) but I was unable to figure out how to use it   to do a simple math date calculation.

I came up with this but I am not sure if this is the way to go. Suggestions are welcomed.

```
var dPast = 'January 4, 2018'
var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
var d2 = new Date(dPast);
var dCalc = Math.abs((d1-d2)/31556952000);   // difference in milliseconds
var diff = Math.round(10 * dCalc)/10;   // difference in years rounded to tenth

alert('It has been ' + diff + ' years since ' + dPast);
```

Comment: Have you tried datefns - https://date-fns.org/?

Comment: I am just starting to learn JS, can you please provide a specific example of how the date calculation would look like using the approach you suggested?

Comment: Would be very easy if you go for momentjs instead

Comment: agree with @Viney

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might want to check moment.js. It just 2.6kb size or you can use a cdn

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Check fo the `diff` function

```js
var dPast = 'January 4, 2018'
var todaysDate = moment(new Date()); //"now"
var pastDate = moment(new Date(dPast));

var years = todaysDate.diff(pastDate, 'years');
var months = todaysDate.diff(pastDate, 'months');

console.log(years + ' years, ' + months % 12 + ' months');
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@slyfox, It would be better to first subtract the milliseconds of the indicated date from the current and then format it to your desired output.

```
var dPast = 'January 5, 2018';
var indicatedD = new Date(dPast);
var d = new Date();

// subtract the current time's milliseconds from the dPast date's.
var elapsed = new Date(d.getTime() - indicatedD.getTime());

// get the years.
var years = Math.abs(elapsed.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
console.log('It has been ' + years + ' years since ' + dPast);
```

As you are just starting out, so it's good to explore on your own but as you get comfortable I'd suggest you to use a date library such as **moment.js**, as it's more reliably and has got tons of built-in methods which will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Agree with this. If you have plenty of time to study basics, it is much better but if you need it immediately try to use date libraries. BTW Is this working for leap year?

Answer (score 0):

This code can be run after testing, which can be accurate to the minute.

```js
/**
 * 计算日期&时间间隔/推算几天前后是哪一天
 * @author 江村暮
 */

//平年
const ordinaryYearMonth: Array<any> = [null, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

//闰年
const leapYearMonth: Array<any> = [null, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

/**
 * 是否为闰年
 **/
const isLeap = (year: number): boolean => {
    if (year % 400 === 0 && year % 100 === 0) return true
    if (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) return true
    return false
}

//解析时间串
type Num = number
const parseTime = (time: string): {
    hour: Num;
    min: Num
} => {
    var bound: Num = time.indexOf(':')
    return {
        hour: parseInt(time.substring(0, bound)),
        min: parseInt(time.substring(bound + 1))
    }
}

//解析日期串
const parseDate = (date = '2020-03-06'): Readonly<{
    year: number;
    month: number;
    day: number;
    isLeap: boolean
}> => {
    var match = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/.exec(date);
    if (!match) throw Error
    return {
        year: parseInt(match[1]),
        month: parseInt(match[2].replace(/^0/, '')),
        day: parseInt(match[3].replace(/^0/, '')),
        isLeap: isLeap(parseInt(match[1]))
    }
}

const calDiffer = (
    defaultDateEarly: string,
    defaultDateLate: string,
    defaultTimeEarly?: string,
    defaultTimeLate?: string
): {
    day: number,
    hour: number,
    min: number,
    overflowHour: number,
    overflowMin: number
} => {

    var dateEarly = parseDate(defaultDateEarly)
        , dateLate = parseDate(defaultDateLate)
        , diffDay: number;

    //两个日期在同一年
    if (dateLate.year === dateEarly.year) {
        var numOfEarlyMonthDay = dateEarly.isLeap ? leapYearMonth[dateEarly.month] : ordinaryYearMonth[dateEarly.month]
        // 两个日期在同一月份
        if (dateLate.month === dateEarly.month) {
            diffDay = dateLate.day - dateEarly.day
        } else {
            diffDay = dateLate.day + numOfEarlyMonthDay - dateEarly.day;//两个日期所在月的非整月天数和
            for (let i = dateEarly.month; i < dateLate.month - 1; i++) {
                diffDay += (dateLate.isLeap) ? leapYearMonth[i] : ordinaryYearMonth[i]
            }
        }
    } else {
        //这一年已过天数
        var lateYearDay = dateLate.day;
        for (let i = dateLate.month - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            lateYearDay += (dateLate.isLeap) ? leapYearMonth[i] : ordinaryYearMonth[i]
        }
        console.log(lateYearDay)

        //那一年剩下天数
        var earlyYearDay = 0
        for (let i = 13 - dateEarly.month; i >= 1; i--) {
            earlyYearDay += (dateLate.isLeap) ? leapYearMonth[i] : ordinaryYearMonth[i]
        }
        earlyYearDay -= dateEarly.day
        console.log(earlyYearDay)

        //相隔年份天数，如：年份为2010 - 2020，则计算2011 - 2019的天数
        var diffYear: number[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= dateLate.year - dateEarly.year - 1; i++) {
            diffYear.push(dateEarly.year + i + 1)
        }

        diffDay = earlyYearDay + lateYearDay
        diffYear.map(year => {
            diffDay += isLeap(year) ? 366 : 365
        })
    }

    //计算这天剩下的时间与那天已经过的分钟之和
    var timeEarly = parseTime(defaultTimeEarly || '00:00'),
        timeLate = parseTime(defaultTimeLate || '00:00');
    var overflowDiffMin = 60 * (25 - timeEarly.hour + timeLate.hour) + 60 - timeEarly.min + timeLate.min
    var diffMin = (diffDay - 1) * 1440 + overflowDiffMin
    console.log(timeEarly, timeLate, diffMin)
    return {
        day: diffDay,
        overflowHour: Math.floor(diffMin/60) - diffDay * 24,
        overflowMin: diffMin % 60,//(overflowDiffMin - 1440 * diffDay) % 60,
        hour: Math.floor(diffMin/60),
        min: diffMin % 60
    }
}

export { calDiffer }
```

Answer (score 0):

Original solution can be found here: https://forums.getdrafts.com/t/calculate-years-and-months-since-a-specific-date/8082/3

This code was a step up as I wanted to keep things simple as a beginner. However, I went step by step to understand it. I will leave a footprint here for my own reference and for anyone in the future.

```
/*********
Day.js is a minimalist JavaScript library that parses, validates, manipulates, and displays dates and times for modern browsers with a largely Moment.js-compatible API.

Step 1: Download the dayjs.min.js file from the JSDelivr site: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/dayjs

Step 2 : Save the downloaded file to the Drafts/Library/Scripts folder in iCloud. 
*/

require('dayjs.min.js'); // Tell Drafts to use Dayjs script

let dPast = 'December 4, 2017'; // set the date from the past
let d1 = dayjs(); // tell Dayjs to parse the date
let d2 = dayjs(dPast); // set the current date

/******
* Math.round() - is a function that is used to return a number rounded to the nearest integer (whole) value.

* To get the difference in months, pass the month as the second argument. By default, dayjs#diff will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number, pass true as the third argument.

*Read more: https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference#docsNav
*/

let m = Math.round(d1.diff(d2, 'month', true));

/******
* Divide the number of months (obtained earlier) by 12 to see how many years. This number will be rounded to an integer (whole number). If the result is less than 1 (years) the rounded number will be set to 0. For example 11/12 = 0.916666667 This will be rounded to 0.
*/

let y = Math.floor(m/12); 
if (y == 0) {
  alert(`\n${m} months since ${dPast}`); // Alert that "x" number of months but no years have passed since the indicated date.
}
/* Remainder
An amount left over after division (happens when the first number does not divide exactly by the other). Example: 19 cannot be divided exactly by 5. The closest you can get without going over is 3 x 5 = 15, which is 4 less than 19. So 4 is the remainder.

In JavaScript, the remainder operator (%) returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of the dividend.
*/
else {
  m = m % 12;
  if (m == 0) {
    alert(`${y} years since ${dPast}`); //If the remainder is 0 than a whole year(s) have passed since the indicated date but no months.
  }
  else {
    alert(`${y} years, ${m} months since ${dPast}`); // Years and months since the indicated date.
  }
}
```